# How i can take list of running apps from remote websphere app server in my java app?

Tags: java, websphere

How i can take list of running apps from remote websphere app server in my java app? If i have login, pass and url to admin console.

Comment: By "apps" do you mean web applications running on *that* Websphere instance?

Comment: Yes, remote WAS has some running apps. My java  app in a different  java application server on other host.

Comment: And you want to do this why? Isn't weblogic console enough?

Comment: The goal is to monitor multiple WAS servers, monitor the availability of datasources and list of  running applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is it:

```
        java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
        props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP);
        props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, "localhost");
        props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, "8880");
        props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "true");
        props.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, "admin");
        props.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, "111111");

        client = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(props);

        //Проверяем список запущенных приложений
        AppManagement appM = AppManagementProxy.getJMXProxyForClient(client);
        Vector apps = appM.listApplications(null, null, null);
        System.out.println("     Status    |   Application   ");

        for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++) {
            String queryString = "WebSphere:type=Application,name=" + apps.get(i) + ",*";
            ObjectName queryAppObj = new ObjectName(queryString);
            Set<?> result = client.queryNames(queryAppObj, null);
            if (result.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("     Stopped   |   " + apps.get(i));
            } else {
                System.out.println("     Running   |   " + apps.get(i));
            }
        }
```

Simple output:

```
 Status    |   Application   

 Running   |   query
 Running   |   SamplesGallery
 Stopped   |   ivtApp
 Stopped   |   DefaultApplication
 Running   |   PlantsByWebSphere
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [AdminClientFactory](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/management/AdminClientFactory.html) API to locate the `type=Application,*` MBeans.